# Trying to Play Old Version of Game using web archive, got uncaught syntax error

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to play a browser game as it was before. I thought of using the wayback machine. I selected this result: https://web.archive.org/web/20190704230523/http://armorgames.com/ngu-idle-game/18444

My browser, Google Chrome, gave me the following error: webarchive.org says: An error occurred running the Unity content on this page. See your browser JavaScript for more info. The error was: Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The URL '/_static/wombatWorkers.js' is invalid.

I was wondering what this error means and if its fixable. Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhRW8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the error message, it's trying to access `/_static/wombatWorkers.js`, which is no longer a valid URL when the site is being accessed through a subdirectory of another domain.
Originally that URL would've expanded to:

```
http://armorgames.com/_static/wombatWorkers.js
```

But when visiting the site through web.archive.org, it expands to:

```
https://web.archive.org/_static/wombatWorkers.js
```

...which has nothing useful there (just a 404 error page that doesn't look anything like valid JS code, thus the SyntaxError). What the game *wanted* to access would actually be at:

```
https://web.archive.org/web/20190704230523/http://armorgames.com/_static/wombatWorkers.js
```

Normally the Wayback Machine *tries* to catch and rewrite such URL references (all URLs within standard HTML tags are rewritten to include "/www/YYMMDD/"), but there are situations when the URL comes from within JavaScript code and the archival script has no way of knowing which JS strings looking like "/this/that" are indeed URLs that should be rewritten and which ones aren't URLs at all but just strings that look *kinda* like URLs.

Related to that: Unfortunately, because archive.org didn't know that `/_static/wombatWorkers.js` was a URL, it **has not archived** that page either, so even if you use a browser extension to catch and rewrite these requests, you still won't be able to play the game.

Answer (score 0):

The Wayback Machine cannot be depended upon for making a complete and
working copy of a website - its backup algorithms are not perfect.

But why are you trying to play the NGU Idle game from the past,
when it also exists today with a whole fandom community?

Point your browser to
[NGU Idle Wiki](https://ngu-idle.fandom.com/wiki/NGU_Idle_Wiki)
and just
[play the game](https://www.kongregate.com/games/somethingggg/ngu-idle)!